# images are not showing up in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

hi I am creating a product listing it works fine in all browsers but in IE the images are not showing up.following is my code for this:

Images container:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="height"></div>
  <img class="prod-image" width="auto" height="auto"src="xyz.jpg">
</div>
```

css:
this one is reset:

```
*{margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
  float:left;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
.image-container *{
  float:none;
  display:table;
}
.image-container{text-align:center;}
.prod-image {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Images of the products are not showing up in IE but in other browsers it is working fine please help me :( following is the link of the online site:
[Here](http://www.findyogi.com/mobiles)

Comment: your HTML for `width` and `height` is completely unnecessary., and the lack of a space between `height` and `src` is probably causing it.

Comment: [233 Errors, 75 warning(s)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.findyogi.com%2Fmobiles&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: In IE I get 


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 11
Char: 405
Code: 0
URI: http://www.findyogi.com/scripts/less-1.0.21.min.js

Comment: Which version of IE is it? Or is it all versions?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock I've tried on ie9 and in developers tool if checked ie7,8,9 veiw...

Comment: @PlantTheIdea sir please give me more details please

Comment: @j08691 this error is coming in every page i am use less framework I am not able to remove that error too

Comment: @BharatSoni - provided an answer clarifying what i mean, as well as additional recommendations to make the `img` declaration valid HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `auto` value from the width and height attributes on the `<img>` and they'll show up as you expect .. using `auto` for those attributes is actually invalid in HTML

http://linenwoods.com/images/IE.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You should change this:

```
<img class="prod-image" width="auto" height="auto"src="xyz.jpg">
```

To this:

```
<img class="prod-image" src="xyz.jpg" alt="" />
```

Three things that changed:

1. Get rid of `width="auto"` and `height="auto"` (unnecessary, and `auto` is an invalid value)
2. Have a space before the `src` (likely IE is barking at this)
3. Close the tag at the end with `/` (an xHTML thing, but just good practice)

This will fall in line with accepted standards, and will work.